# Failed To Save Firebase Data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to save Data to firebase.

I am using loading bar to indicate the process then if the saving process is success or failed it will bid dismiss.

but in my code loading bar doesn't dismiss, I think it is looping again. Here is my code :

```
private EditText namalengkap, namapanggilan, nisn, kelas;
private Button btnsimpan, btnkeluar;
private ProgressDialog loadingBar;
private String nisnsiswa, kelassiswa, namasiswa, panggilansiswa;
```

Process to save start here :

```
    btnsimpan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            simpandata();
        }
    });
```

the method "simpandata" will proceed to these code :

```
private void simpandata() {
    namasiswa = namalengkap.getText().toString();
    panggilansiswa = namapanggilan.getText().toString();
    kelassiswa = kelas.getText().toString();
    nisnsiswa = nisn.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(namasiswa)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ketik Nama Siswa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(panggilansiswa)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ketik Nama Panggilan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(kelassiswa)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ketik Nama Kelas Siswa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(nisnsiswa)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ketik Nomor NISN Siswa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        loadingBar.setTitle("Memasukan Data Siswa");
        loadingBar.setMessage("Silahkan Tunggu");
        loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        loadingBar.show();

        verifikasisimpan();
    }
}
```

in above code loading bar start to show and then proceed to method "verifikasisimpan" with this code.

```
private void verifikasisimpan() {
    final DatabaseReference datasiswa;
    datasiswa = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    datasiswa.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

              if (!(dataSnapshot.child("Siswa").child(nisnsiswa).exists()))
             {

            HashMap<String, Object> siswadataMap = new HashMap<>();
            siswadataMap.put("nisnsiswa", nisnsiswa);
            siswadataMap.put("kelassiswa", kelassiswa);
            siswadataMap.put("namasiswa", namasiswa);
            siswadataMap.put("panggilansiswa", panggilansiswa);
            datasiswa.child("Siswa").child(nisnsiswa).updateChildren(siswadataMap)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(InputDataActivity.this, "Data Telah Tersimpan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loadingBar.dismiss();

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(InputDataActivity.this, "Penyimpanan Data Gagal, Silahkan Coba Lagi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }
            else {

                Toast.makeText(InputDataActivity.this,"Siswa  "+ namasiswa + " telah terdaftar.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadingBar.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText (InputDataActivity.this,"Silahkan Daftarkan Siswa Lain", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

I supposed to show toast on success or failure and dismiss loader, but i guess the apps didn't reach "if task successfully or unsuccessful part", loading bar keep showing so i cancel it by pressing backspace, i checked the database, the data is not saved, where i miss it,

PS : i copied the procedure from my previous working code.

Comment: There is a possibility that you didn't set up firebase permission. For testing you should set both `Read` and `Write` to true.

Comment: already set it true for both read and write

Comment: please also add your build.gradle file then